# Jackson Serialize overloaded output

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have an API which is being extended to be consumed by another system. Pre-req's exist whereby each frontend has different expectations for one json field.

Example:
The response field 'amount' must be either a String or an int, depending on which value I receive from downstream. So for some instances I will return a string value in the json, while in others I will return int.

Expected json outputs:

```
{
    "amount": 21
}
```

or

```
{
    "amount": "21"
}
```

I have done the following:

```
class Response {

    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private int amount;
    
    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private String amountString;

// Getters and setters
```

Hoping that I would be able to return either an int or String value for the json field 'amount' but I'm getting the following error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "amount"

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that.  The element in your JSON is called `amount`, you can not bind it to 2 different variables.

You are getting this exception because the `@JsonProperty("amount")` is used on 2 seperate class fields.

It is best to create 2 different response:

Example:

```
class FrontEndResponse1 {

    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private int amount;

   //getter/setter
    
}

class FrontEndResponse2 {

    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private String amount;

    //getter/setter
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this won't work with typed return values.

Unless you're fine with providing 2 endpoints with different return types you could return a plain `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Response`:

```
public Map<String, Object> awkwardMethod(boolean wantString) {
  Response response = new Response();
  ... // do business logic
  return Map.of("amount", wantString ? String.value(response.amount) : response.amount);
}
```

To be clear: I'm not encouraging you to do this as you'll loose type information for the return value and introduce error prone manual mapping. I'm just providing a solution for a problem that should be fixed by providing a clear API and clients sticking to this API.